# Highlight block of injected code

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, gvim, vim-windows

windows 10/ gvim 1-1802.

I use Javascript and there are sometimes blocks of HTML code that need to be inside a particular region that can be indicated by `"""`, for example .

I have a similar situation with Python files. I need to enable syntax highlighting for some block of text containing code from another programming language.

I am searching for how to to enable a new `syntax` file from inside of a file that already uses a `syntax` file.

Comment: `:help sh-awk-embed` or something along those lines is a good start

Comment: I think this question is a direct duplicate of [Treat string literals as a different language](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/42/1841). Also some interesting related questions are [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9387/1841) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7445/1841)